# How to understand notation $\otimes$ for multivariate Gaussian distribution?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, kronecker-product

I am confused about the notation $\otimes$ for multivariate Gaussian distribution. For $K=(K_{s,r})$ and $1\le s, r \le n$ a n by n covariance matrix, we write
$$(Z_1, Z_2, \dots, Z_n)\sim \mathcal{N}(0, K \otimes I_m)$$
to mean that $Z_1, Z_2, \dots, Z_n$ is a collection of centered, jointly  Gaussian random vectors in $R^m$, with covariances $\mathbb{E}(Z_sZ_r^T)=K_{s,r}I_m$.

Q1: What is $\mathcal{N}(0, K \otimes I_m)$? I remember that we always use the notation $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ to represent a multivariate Gaussian distribution with mean vector $\mu$ and covariance $\Sigma$. Is there any difference?

I know that is

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    K_{11}       & K_{12} & K_{13} & \dots & K_{1n} \\
    K_{21}       & K_{22} & K_{23} & \dots & K_{2n} \\
      ... \\            
    K_{n1}       & K_{n2} & K_{n3} & \dots & K_{nn}
\end{bmatrix} \otimes I_m$$

Q2: Why $\mathbb{E}(Z_sZ_r^T)=K_{s,r}I_m$?

Comment: In this context, $\otimes$ refers to the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of matrices. The point is that we know that the covariance matrix of the distribution has the form $\Sigma = K \otimes I_m$ for some covariance matrix $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-covariance_matrix), covariance between the random vectors $Z_s$ and $Z_r$ is

$$\operatorname{Cov}(Z_s,Z_r)=E[(Z_s-E(Z_s))(Z_r-E(Z_r))^T]$$

The above is an $m\times m$ matrix since each $Z_i$ is an $m\times 1$ vector. And because $Z_i$ is centered, its mean vector is $E(Z_i)=0$. This gives you

$$E[Z_sZ_r^T]=K_{s,r}I_m$$

The dispersion of $(Z_1,Z_2,\ldots,Z_n)$ is then the $mn\times mn$ matrix $\Sigma=(K_{s,r}I_m)_{1\le s,r\le n}$ :

$$\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}
    K_{11}I_m & K_{12}I_m & \cdots & K_{1n}I_m \\
    K_{21}I_m & K_{22}I_m & \cdots & K_{2n}I_m \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots \\            
    K_{n1}I_m & K_{n2}I_m & \cdots & K_{nn}I_m
\end{bmatrix} $$

This is exactly the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of the matrices $K=(K_{s,r})_{1\le s,r\le n}$ and $I_m$, written as

$$\Sigma=K \otimes I_m$$